# Why can I console.log the value but not setState?

Tags: reactjs, google-translate

I apologize in advance if there is a super obvious solution but I'm very new to React.js.

I'm working with the google-translate api to build a simple translator component.The text input is stored in the state and used by translateInput(), I then want to set the state with the translated text. Unfortunately, I can't, I can however console.log the value which is returned by the googleTranslate function. Why is this happening? Do I have to bind the callback function somehow?

Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { googleTranslate } from '../utils/googleTranslate';

class Translator extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
             input:'',
             translatedInput: '',
        }
    }

    handleTextInput = e => {
        this.setState({input:e.target.value})
    }

    translateInput = () => {
        googleTranslate.translate([this.state.input],"en", "de", 
        function (err, translations){        
      //this.setState({translatedInput:translations.translatedText}) 
      //TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
        console.log(translations.translatedText)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context of the function you are using does not have access to the component through the `this` keyword because you're creating a function scope with the `function` keyword.  Using an arrow function should do the trick:

```
 translateInput = () => {
        googleTranslate.translate([this.state.input],"en", "de", 
        (err, translations) => {        
      this.setState({translatedInput:translations.translatedText}) 
        console.log(translations.translatedText)
        })
    }
```